# File upload issue in host server

Tags: php, file-upload

When try to upload a image file, hosting server makes warning sometimes. If i try uploading the same file in succeeding tries the image will be uploaded.

Warning:

```
Warning (2): move_uploaded_file(files/photos/3.jpg) [http://php.net/function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied [APP/controllers/components/file_upload.php, line 55]
Warning (2): move_uploaded_file() [http://php.net/function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpUutr9Z' to 'files/photos/3.jpg' [APP/controllers/components/file_upload.php, line 55]
```

File Upload

```
if ( is_uploaded_file($file_temp) ) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $destination . $filename . '.' . $extension)) {
    $error = "SUCCESS";
    return $error;
    } else {
    $error = "ERROR";
    return $error;
    }
}
```

Here when warning comes 'ERROR' in else portion is also returned with warning...

How I can correct it ?

It is working nice in local server...

Comment: Are you saying that files that you have uploaded already, or that already exist are able to upload and new ones are not? But I agree about the permissions with Valerly.

Comment: An file 'test.jpg', first time it may show warning, but next time it may uploaded to server ...

Answer (score 2):

Probably your script do not have permission to write to destination directory.

Comment: If permission is error, then file will not be uploaded to server isn't it ?   Here the file is uploaded to server, but only in some cases the error is displaying and uploading fails

Answer (score 0):

So is `APP/controllers/components/files/photos/3.jpg` where you want to save your uploads? If so then its a permissions problem.

Or do you mean: `WEB_ROOT/files/photos/3.jpg` if so you need to change your code too:

```
if ( is_uploaded_file($file_temp) ) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($file_temp, '/'.$destination.$filename.'.'.$extension)) {
    $error = "SUCCESS";
    return $error;
    } else {
    $error = "ERROR";
    return $error;
    }
}
```

notice the forward slash `'/'.$destination`

Comment: I'am using framework cake php, the destination is `webroot/files/photos/3.jpg`. But some time code in question works fine.. Only certain cases it returns a warning ...

Answer (score 0):

Check the **CHMOD** on the directory and on the file. Usually PHP is ran like *root*, but you can still forbid it's access with CHMOD.